# Simple injector getting instance of UserStore

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, simple-injector

This is how I'm registering my identity classes:

```
     container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppDbContext>();

        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IAppUserStore>(() =>
            new AppUserStore(container.GetInstance<AppDbContext>()));

        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppUserManager>();


        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<AppSignInManager>();

        container.RegisterInitializer<AppUserManager>(
            manager => InitializeUserManager(manager, app));
```

Account controller:

```
 private readonly AppSignInManager _signInManager;
    private readonly AppUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController(AppUserManager userManager, AppSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

Everything is good, but when I try to type something like

```
 var test = new Container().GetInstance<IAppUserStore>();
```

I get next error: **No registration for type IAppUserStore could be found**

But `GetInstance<AppDbContext>` goes ok

Why can't i get those instances? Container.Verify() compiles without errors.

Comment: You are new'ing a new container up. A new container does not have any instances.

Comment: But why GetInctance<AppDbContext> works?

Comment: Are you saying you can access `new Container().GetInstance<AppDbContext>()`? because I do not believe you.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mbHEYxw.png

Comment: What if you set the `Container` as a dependency on the constructor, and access your `IAppUserStore` though `_container.GetInstance<IAppUserStore>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var test = new Container().GetInstance<IAppUserStore>();
> ```

Will fail because you are creating a new instance of the Container that has no registrations and therefore does not know which implementation (i.e. class) you are asking for when you say `IAppUserStore` (interface).

> ```
> Container().GetInstance<AppDbContext>()
> ```

Will work because you are asking for a class and the Container will create an instance of a class even if it not already registered *as long as the Container can resolve all of the constructor arguments of that Type*.

Try to avoid referencing the Container outside of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). If `AccountController` needs `IAppUserStore` then you should consider adding it to the constructor of `AccountController`.